# Send object to UITableView controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Hope someone can help me with this, it has me totally stumped

My application has two view controllers in a tab bar...

```
//Create two view controllers
UIViewController *vc1 = [[RecordingViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[SavedViewController alloc] init];//this is a tableViewController

//Make an array with the two view controllers
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

//Release the two view controllers since they are now retained by the array
[vc1 release];
[vc2 release];

//Attach the ViewControllers to the tabBar
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

I then have another object (`fileHandler`) which wants to send an object called `capture` to `vc2` for addition to an `NSMutableArray`, so from that class I send...

```
[vc2 addToCapturesArray:capture];
```

Of course this does not work and I just get the "vc2 undeclared" message from the compiler. How do I let my `fileHandler` class know about the vc2 instance? Thanks in advance for all your help.

---

Thanks for the help. It all now compiles, however the method in vc2 is not getting called 
for some reason. The code now looks like this...

```
    @interface Rolling_VideoAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;

//Tab bar
UITabBarController *tabBarController;

//Create an ivar so that the app delegate can hold a reference
SavedViewController *_vc2;
```

}
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    //Create a property so we can access vc2 from the outside
    @property (nonatomic, retain) SavedViewController *vc2;

```
#import "Rolling_VideoAppDelegate.h"

//Import view controllers
#import "RecordingViewController.h"
#import "SavedViewController.h"

@implementation Rolling_VideoAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize vc2 = _vc2;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


//Create an instance of tabBarView controller
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

//Create two view controllers
UIViewController *vc1 = [[RecordingViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[SavedViewController alloc] init];
self.vc2 = _vc2;


//Make an array with the two view controllers
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

//Release the two view controllers since they are now retained by the array
[vc1 release];
[vc2 release];

//Attach the ViewControllers to the tabBar
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

//Place  the tabBar on the window
[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

The file handler looks like this...

```
    Captures *capture = [[Captures alloc]initWithVideoPath:savePath];
NSLog(@"Instance of capture called:\n VideoPath: %@ \n Geo: %@, \n UserNotes: %@", [capture videoPath], [capture location], [capture userNotes]);

// Get a reference to the app delegate, and then access the vc2 property
Rolling_VideoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Rolling_VideoAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

[appDelegate.vc2 addToCapturesArray:capture];
```

Thanks again for all the help.

Rich

Comment: Is there any reason that the fileHandler class can't be an instance variable within the second view controller?

Comment: Just so you know, `>` starts a blockquote environment; indenting by four spaces starts a code environment. http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your vc1/vc2 are in the AppDelegate, then what you want is to extend the app delegate something like this

```
@interface AppDelegate
{
    // Create an ivar so that the app delegate can hold a reference
    VC2Class *_vc2;
}

// Create a property so that you can access if from the outside
@property(nonatomic, retain) VC2Class *vc2;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

// Map the property to the ivar
@synthesize vc2 = _vc2;

// When you are freeing the app delegate make sure to nil 
// the property to release it
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.vc2 = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When you create vc2 in addition to the rest of your code do this:

```
// Since this is a retain property it will do the retain you need 
// when assigning to self.vc2
self.vc2 = vc2;
```

Now in your file namanger, do this:

```
// Get a reference to the app delegate, and then access the vc2 property
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
VC2Class *vc2 = appDelegate.vc2;
```

Then you can call into it as normal. Make sure to include `#import "VC2Class.h"` at the top of your file namanger

@end

Comment: typo: `VC2Class *vc2 = appDelegate.vc2;` :-)

Comment: Issues sorted with a little playing around. Many thanks guys.